# Retrieving YAML parameters during runtime in App Engine (Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, runtime, yaml

Is it possible to programmatically retrieve any of the YAML parameters during run-time? Are they stored in the environment somewhere?

Good example would be to automatically find the application version and to add it as a comment in the landing HTML page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, but some of the data is available from os.environ - for example, `os.environ['APPLICATION_ID']`, and `os.environ['CURRENT_VERSION_ID']`.

Comment: Works. Thanks! So, the last 1 in the version ID is the API version, is it? (ie) I tried os.environ['CURRENT_VERSION_ID'] and got <app-version-number>.1

Comment: CURRENT_VERSION_ID is in the form 'major.minor'. 'major' is the version name you set in app.yaml; 'minor' is an ID generated by the system. On the dev_appserver, minor will always be 1, while in production it will vary from version to version.

Answer (score 4):

No (except for what environment settings CGI and WSGI standards mandate).  If you need the full contents of `app.yaml` to use in your code, then I'd recommend keeping a copy of `app.yaml` (e.g. as `my.yaml` in the same directory), and doing

```
import yaml

...

data = yaml.load(open('my.yaml', 'rb'))
```

to get the required dictionary `data`.

Comment: You may be able to specify app.yaml should be uploaded with the app as well.  Perhaps you can adjust skip_files so it will upload.  See http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Skipping_Files.

Comment: @Robert, good idea, +1 -- this way you can avoid the `my.yaml` copy (you still do need the `yaml.load(open('app.yaml', 'rb'))` as in my A, though.

Answer (score 2):

In PyYAML, the `__init__.py` file in the yaml folder has a global variable `__version__`, so

```
#import yaml
print yaml.__version__
```